# can't load any storyboard in XCTestCase

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

```
 func testExample() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
    //   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
}
```

getting the 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle' error.

i have tried to use also the line it comment, tried to select Main.storyboard under the test unit also, nothing helped.

Comment: tried also using Bundle.main

Comment: no spelling error either, works fine when launching the app

Comment: Make sure the storyboard is also “attached” to the testing target

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that, just declare a variable and assign the storyboard in this variable.

var mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard?

override func setUp() {
super.setUp()
self.mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
}

Comment: dosen't work.. mabye becuase i'm running ui test and not unit test?